# What's an appropriate blending configuration to enable masking with pixel shaders?

Tags: glsl, webgl, masking

I'd like to mask out colors in a framebuffer using the output of a pixel shader but the results I'm getting are pretty counterintuitive. I'm thinking that the problem stems from the blend mode configuration. Effectively, I want to apply alpha calculated in a pixel shader to values that have already been written to a framebuffer by a prior quad/pixel shader (using the new output to erase portions of the previous output). Rather than replacing the contents of the framebuffer with the new values, it looks like they are being blended together.

I've experimented with a wide range of different blend configurations but nothing really works like I'd expect.

```
//Shader snippet:
vec4 previousColor =  texture2D(baseUniform, gl_FragCoord.xy * screenDimsRatioUniform);
newValue = previousColor * (1.0 - newValue.a);

//Typical blending configuration:
gl.blendFuncSeparate(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE, gl.ONE);
gl.blendEquation(gl.FUNC_ADD);
```

I can see that the mask is being applied across the framebuffer, however the output values never achieve full transparency, even in areas where the new color output should cause newValue.a to go to 1. I assume this is because the output is actually being blended with the previous output, rather than replacing it. I've experimented with disabling blending, using subtraction, as well as a wide range of permutations of blendFuncSeperate, but nothing is giving the desired output. Any suggestions would be appreciated...

Comment: `previousColor =  texture2D(baseUniform` Where exactly is this texture coming from? Are you reading from the current framebuffer? And if so, are you taking the proper precautions when doing so?

Comment: Hi, in this case I am not reading from the current framebuffer, although I do sometimes read from other framebuffers. All of that is working fine, and I have a wide range of other blending mechanisms implemented and working... I'm merely challenged when it comes to manipulating the alpha of colors that are already in the current frame buffer via a second texture. Hope that makes sense...

Comment: @NicolBolas, in WebGL you can't read from the same texture you're drawing to. Unlike OpenGL in WebgL it will generate INVALID_OPERATION on the draw call and so the draw will not even happen.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Without seeing more code it's hard to help. Masking in a shader is usually something like `outputColor = mix(colorFromImage1, colorFromImage2, 0to1Mask)`; blending would be off since you don't need any blending.